# Filtering Each Object With Equal Value Into Individual Arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'll just cut straight to the chase.

Let's say I have a simple array of objects, where some objects' dates are equal:

```
[{value: 67, date: 91}, {value: 48, date: 91}, {value: 15, date: 92}, {value: 77, date: 92}, {value: 10, date: 93}, {value: 5, date: 93}]
```

How can I filter the array so that objects with equal dates return in their own individual arrays like this:

```
[{value: 67, date: 91}, {value: 48, date: 91}]
[{value: 15, date: 92}, {value: 77, date: 92}]
[{value: 10, date: 93}, {value: 5, date: 93}]
```

Comment: Is it known that the values for the _date_ properties are in a certain range (e.g. 91-93)?

Comment: Is expected result a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: No @guest271314 , tho that isn't a problem. As long as objects with equal dates are in their own arrays, then we good. The values don't matter, those can be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var array = [{value: 67, date: 91}, {value: 48, date: 91}, {value: 15, date: 92}, {value: 77, date: 92}, {value: 10, date: 93}, {value: 5, date: 93}]; 
filteredArray = array.reduce((pre,curr)=> {
    // check if the object has unqiue date as key
    if(!pre.hasOwnProperty(curr['date'])){
        // if not, create an array with the unique date as key
        pre[curr['date']] = [];
    }
    //push current value to array based on date
    pre[curr['date']].push(curr);
    // return the object 
    return pre;
}, {}); 
console.log(filteredArray);
console.log(Object.keys(filteredArray));
var asArray = Object.keys(filteredArray).reduce((pre,curr)=>{pre.push(filteredArray[curr]); return pre},[])
console.log(asArray);
```

For notes, refer to comments.

**EDIT:**

This way you can easily get the unique dates. By doing `Object.keys(filteredArray)` or extract the arrays by just doing `asArray 
 = Object.keys(filteredArray).reduce(e)=>{prev.push(filteredArray[e]); return pre},[]}`

Comment: This removes 3 of the objects. I need to move objects with equal dates into their own array. All objects must remain.

Comment: removes 3 of the object? which ones are you referring to?

Comment: Even better. Thx mate!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for..of`, `in` operator to check if `date` is property of an object, if true, add `value`, `date` of object to array of object at that property

```js
let arr = [{value: 67, date: 91}
          , {value: 67, date: 91}
          , {value: 67, date: 92}
          , {value: 67, date: 92}
          , {value: 67, date: 93}
          , {value: 67, date: 93}
          ];

let res = {};

for (let {value, date} of arr) {
  if (!(date in res)) res[date] = Array({value,date})
  else res[date] = [...res[date], {value, date}]
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Be careful with using `in` operator : `it return true if key is present even in  prototype chain`. A better and safe way is to use :`res.hasOwnPropert(date)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = [{value: 67, date: 91}, {value: 67, date: 91}, {value: 67, date: 92}, {value: 67, date: 92}, {value: 67, date: 93}, {value: 67, date: 93}];

var storage = {};
items.map((item) => {
    storage[JSON.stringify(item)] = true;
})
    
for( element in storage ) {
    console.log( JSON.parse(element) );
}
```

A small consideration about this code, is the elements on each object must be ordered, otherwise is going to fall for example if you have:

```
{ value: 67, date: 91 }
{ date: 91, value: 67 }
```

Both are different elements using the code above.

Comment: This removes 3 of the objects. I need to move objects with equal dates into their own array. All objects must remain